# Deploy nuxt js universal project in shared hosting

Tags: apache, vue.js, cpanel, nuxtjs, namecheap

**I want to deploy a  nuxt js project in shared hosting and I make a sub directory to call api from laravel. I am using the set up node js app option from cpanel . my hosting provider is namecheap  but I got this error**

```
App 1010748 output: /home/zanaehlf/public_html/app/nuxt.config.js:1
App 1010748 output: export default {
App 1010748 output: ^^^^^^
App 1010748 output: 
App 1010748 output: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
App 1010748 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
App 1010748 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
App 1010748 output:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
App 1010748 output:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
App 1010748 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
App 1010748 output:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
App 1010748 output:     at Module.require (/opt/passenger-5.3.7-4.el6.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 1010748 output:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
App 1010748 output:     at start (/home/zanaehlf/public_html/app/app.js:6:19)
App 1010748 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zanaehlf/public_html/app/app.js:23:5)
App 1010748 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
App 1010748 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
App 1010748 output:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
App 1010748 output:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
App 1010748 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
App 1010748 output:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
```

I create a app.js file in tha main directory. here is my app.js file

```
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
   const app = require('express')();
   const port = process.env.port || 3000;
   function start() {
     let config = require('./nuxt.config.js');

     //process.env.DEBUG = 'nuxt:*';

     const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

     const builder = new Builder(nuxt);

      builder.build().catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
  
      app.use(nuxt.render);
      app.listen(port);
    }

start();
```

here is my nuxt.config.js file

```
export default {
    
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
   ** Nuxt target
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
   */
  target: 'server',
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
   */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || '',
      },
    ],
    link: [
      {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.png'},
      {rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css'},
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:300,400,500,700,800,900&display=swap',
      },
    ],
  },
  
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
   */
  plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/globalComponents.js', ssr: false},
    {src: '~plugins/zoom.js', ssr: false}
  ],
  /*
   ** Auto import components
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
   */
  components: true,
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: [],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'nuxt-clipboard2',
    [
      'nuxt-gmaps',
      {
        key: 'AIzaSyCjkssBA3hMeFtClgslO2clWFR6bRraGz0',
        // you can use libraries: ['places']
      },
    ],
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],


  proxy: {
    '/api': { target: 'https://zanaj.com/sub/api/', pathRewrite: {'^/api': ''} }
  },
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://zanaj.com/sub/',
    credentials: false
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
   */
  build: {},
  generate: {
    fallback: true,
  },
  env: {
    MIX_FIREBASE_API_KYE: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_API_KYE,
    MIX_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    MIX_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    MIX_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    MIX_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    MIX_FIREBASE_APP_ID: process.env.MIX_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  },
}
```

Comment: What command do you use to start the application?

Comment: I start application from node js app option in the c panel

Comment: Do you have an SSH access to server? Try to run application using `yarn build && yarn start` Here documentation about production deployment https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands#production-deployment

Comment: I have tried those command but not work. I got error (node:567346) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: